# How to embed multiple youtube audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I want to embed multiple youtube audio so that if 1st audio is playing and if I want to play 2nd audio then 2nd audio will play and 1st audio will stop automatically and if I want to play 3rd audio then 2nd audio will stop automatically and 3rd audio will play.

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player1, player2, player3, player4;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

    var ctrlq1 = document.getElementById("youtube-audio1");
    ctrlq1.innerHTML = '<img id="youtube-icon1" src=""/><div id="youtube-player1"></div>';
    ctrlq1.style.cssText = 'width:150px;margin:2em auto;cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;display:none';
    ctrlq1.onclick = toggleAudio1;

    player1 = new YT.Player('youtube-player1', {
      height: '0',
      width: '0',
      videoId: ctrlq1.dataset.video,
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: ctrlq1.dataset.autoplay,
        loop: ctrlq1.dataset.loop,
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady1,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange1 
      } 
    });

    var ctrlq2 = document.getElementById("youtube-audio2");
    ctrlq2.innerHTML = '<img id="youtube-icon2" src=""/><div id="youtube-player2"></div>';
    ctrlq2.style.cssText = 'width:150px;margin:2em auto;cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;display:none';
    ctrlq2.onclick = toggleAudio2;

    player2 = new YT.Player('youtube-player2', {
      height: '0',
      width: '0',
      videoId: ctrlq2.dataset.video,
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: ctrlq2.dataset.autoplay,
        loop: ctrlq2.dataset.loop,
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady2,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange2
      } 
    });

    var ctrlq3 = document.getElementById("youtube-audio3");
    ctrlq3.innerHTML = '<img id="youtube-icon3" src=""/><div id="youtube-player3"></div>';
    ctrlq3.style.cssText = 'width:150px;margin:2em auto;cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;display:none';
    ctrlq3.onclick = toggleAudio3;

    player3 = new YT.Player('youtube-player3', {
      height: '0',
      width: '0',
      videoId: ctrlq3.dataset.video,
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: ctrlq3.dataset.autoplay,
        loop: ctrlq3.dataset.loop,
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady3,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange3 
      } 
    });

    var ctrlq4 = document.getElementById("youtube-audio4");
    ctrlq4.innerHTML = '<img id="youtube-icon4" src=""/><div id="youtube-player4"></div>';
    ctrlq4.style.cssText = 'width:150px;margin:2em auto;cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;display:none';
    ctrlq4.onclick = toggleAudio4;

    player4 = new YT.Player('youtube-player4', {
      height: '0',
      width: '0',
      videoId: ctrlq4.dataset.video,
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: ctrlq4.dataset.autoplay,
        loop: ctrlq4.dataset.loop,
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady4,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange4 
      } 
    });
  } 

  function togglePlayButton1(play) {    
    document.getElementById("youtube-icon1").src = play ? "https://i.imgur.com/IDzX9gL.png" : "https://i.imgur.com/quyUPXN.png";
  }

  function toggleAudio1() {
    if ( player1.getPlayerState() == 1 || player1.getPlayerState() == 3 ) {
      player1.pauseVideo(); 
      togglePlayButton1(false);
    } else {
      player1.playVideo(); 
      togglePlayButton1(true);
    } 
  } 

  function togglePlayButton2(play) {    
    document.getElementById("youtube-icon2").src = play ? "https://i.imgur.com/IDzX9gL.png" : "https://i.imgur.com/quyUPXN.png";
  }

  function toggleAudio2() {
    if ( player2.getPlayerState() == 1 || player2.getPlayerState() == 3 ) {
      player2.pauseVideo(); 
      togglePlayButton2(false);
    } else {
      player2.playVideo(); 
      togglePlayButton2(true);
    } 
  } 

  function togglePlayButton3(play) {    
    document.getElementById("youtube-icon3").src = play ? "https://i.imgur.com/IDzX9gL.png" : "https://i.imgur.com/quyUPXN.png";
  }

  function toggleAudio3() {
    if ( player3.getPlayerState() == 1 || player3.getPlayerState() == 3 ) {
      player3.pauseVideo(); 
      togglePlayButton3(false);
    } else {
      player3.playVideo(); 
      togglePlayButton3(true);
    } 
  } 

  function togglePlayButton4(play) {    
    document.getElementById("youtube-icon4").src = play ? "https://i.imgur.com/IDzX9gL.png" : "https://i.imgur.com/quyUPXN.png";
  }

  function toggleAudio4() {
    if ( player4.getPlayerState() == 1 || player4.getPlayerState() == 3 ) {
      player4.pauseVideo(); 
      togglePlayButton4(false);
    } else {
      player4.playVideo(); 
      togglePlayButton4(true);
    } 
  } 

  function onPlayerReady1(event) {
    player1.setPlaybackQuality("small");
    document.getElementById("youtube-audio1").style.display = "block";
    togglePlayButton1(player1.getPlayerState() !== 5);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange1(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
      togglePlayButton1(false); 
    }
  }

  function onPlayerReady2(event) {
    player2.setPlaybackQuality("small");
    document.getElementById("youtube-audio2").style.display = "block";
    togglePlayButton2(player2.getPlayerState() !== 5);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange2(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
      togglePlayButton2(false); 
    }
  }

  function onPlayerReady3(event) {
    player3.setPlaybackQuality("small");
    document.getElementById("youtube-audio3").style.display = "block";
    togglePlayButton3(player3.getPlayerState() !== 5);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange3(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
      togglePlayButton3(false); 
    }
  }

  function onPlayerReady4(event) {
    player4.setPlaybackQuality("small");
    document.getElementById("youtube-audio4").style.display = "block";
    togglePlayButton4(player4.getPlayerState() !== 5);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange4(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
      togglePlayButton4(false); 
    }
  }
```

```html
<div data-video="DMl1YJyqEdo" > 
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
    <div style="width:400px;height:300px;">
        <div data-video="JC08Fu3QfJg" data-autoplay="0" data-loop="1" id="youtube-audio1"></div>
        <div data-video="7_WWz2DSnT8" data-autoplay="0" data-loop="1" id="youtube-audio2"></div>
        <div data-video="t3217H8JppI" data-autoplay="0" data-loop="1" id="youtube-audio3"></div>
        <div data-video="cbZ7V2ifh20" data-autoplay="0" data-loop="1" id="youtube-audio4"></div>
        
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What result are seeing at the moment?

Comment: Just pause all the other players when you hit play? Could probably use more DRY

Comment: @HollyLeaves could you please me doing this?

Comment: @ArpitGupta You can implement a pauseAll function and put that before every playVideo() call. That would require minimal refactoring

Comment: @HollyLeaves I am still confused, could you please share working jsfiddle.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
   <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
   <title>Example</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
   <button><div data-video = "....">
       data-autoplay = "0";
       data-loop = "1";
       id= "youtube-audio";
      </div></button>
      <script src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
      <script src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
 </body>
 
  </html>
```

I´m not sure if this is what you meant.
Don´t be confused it won´t work as long you don´t enter part after v= in the http-adress of your video into div data-video =

Answer (score 0):

Just search for the video you want to "extract" the audio from. Then copy the part after "v= ..."  from it´s http-adress. Afterwards insert this to your html code:

```
<div data-video = "....">
    data-autoplay = "0";
    data-loop = "1";
    id= "youtube-audio";
</div>
<script src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
```

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: I am still confused, could you please share working jsfiddle.Thanks for your help

Comment: <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
   <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
   <title>Example</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
   <button><div data-video = "....">
       data-autoplay = "0";
       data-loop = "1";
       id= "youtube-audio";
      </div></button>
      <script src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
      <script src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
 </body>
 
  </html>

Comment: Since I just noticed that the program doesn´t show it the way it should be showen I gave you new answer yousing the full code down below.

Comment: I´ve given you another answer although I´m not entirely sure it´ll work since I´ve never worked with jsfiddle before.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div data-video="VIDEO_ID"  
         data-autoplay="0"         
         data-loop="1"             
         id="youtube-audio">
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
```

Recommended to see full article 
https://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-audio-player/26740/

Comment: I am still confused, could you please share working jsfiddle.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
function pauseAll() {
  player1.pauseVideo(); 
  togglePlayButton1(false);
  player2.pauseVideo(); 
  togglePlayButton2(false);
  ....etc
}
```

Then add

```
function toggleAudio1() {
  if ( player1.getPlayerState() == 1 || player1.getPlayerState() == 3 ) {
    player1.pauseVideo(); 
    togglePlayButton1(false);
  } else {

    pauseAll();       <---

    player1.playVideo(); 
    togglePlayButton1(true);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <button><div data-video = "....">
       data-autoplay = "0";
       data-loop = "1";
       id= "youtube-audio";
      </div></button>
      <script src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
      <script src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
    </body>

  </html>
```

Just remember you have to name the butteon otherwise it´ll just show your code,